# Allow the RSA v1.5 Key Transport Algorithm for WildFly / JBossWS / CXF / WSS4J stack

Tags: cxf, wildfly, wss4j, jbossws

In response to a security advisory (see http://cxf.apache.org/note-on-cve-2011-1096.html) regarding the RSA v1.5 key transport algorithm, both CXF and WSS4J projects have disallowed use of all related algorithms by default.

They have however supplied a configuration tag "ALLOW_RSA15_KEY_TRANSPORT_ALGORITHM" which should re-allow these algorithms (see https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/config.html)

Our problem is getting these frameworks (JBossWS / CXF / WSS4J) to accept/use this configuration setting. We have tried using:

- jboss-webservice.xml
- custom CXF interceptor (setting the param after CXF creates its WSS4J interceptor)
- custom "hacked" WSS4J build  (hardcoding the parameter to "true")

But none of these options seem to actually re-enable support for the RSA v1.5 key transport algorithms.

Does anyone have any idea as to how we could/should specify this configuration parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a test I added to CXF:

https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cxf.git;a=commit;h=a73effb5

Note the server has set "allowRSA15KeyTransportAlgorithm" to "true".

Answer (score 0):

This setting is only applied if the `WSHandlerConstants.ENCRYPT` action is included in the actions for the interceptor.

For instance:

```
Map<String, Object> inProps = new HashMap<>();
inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ALLOW_RSA15_KEY_TRANSPORT_ALGORITHM, "true");
inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, 
    WSHandlerConstants.ENCRYPT + " " +
    WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE);
WSS4JInInterceptor wss4JInInterceptor = new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps);
```